# Fetch and embed lyrics into mp3 via command line

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, mp3, id3

I'm looking for a CLI way to fetch the lyrics of a song from the Internet and embed them as an ID3v2 tag into a music file (“Artist - Title.mp3”). There are half a dozen tools for doing this on Linux but how about Windows?

Comment: Bash now runs on Windows. Would Linux tools work under that?

Answer (score 3):

Some free packages I know of :

- [MP3tag](https://www.mp3tag.de/)
  The standard field for lyrics is `UNSYNCEDLYRICS`.
  Please note, that you have to prefix a language identifier in front of the lyrics, or "xxx" if you want the lyrics to show in any language. Also you have to add two "bars": `xxx||My lyrics`.
- [EasyTAG](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EasyTAG)
  Said to have command-line support, but you would have to download it and see,
  as the online documentation is too brief.
- [eyeD3](http://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
  This is a Python tool, for users of Python.
  An example script can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/nicfit/eyed3/src/5a4ab5730ced8d5d0e21440c7c6ff212f923f9d7/examples/tag_example.py?at=default#cl-55).
  It also has a command-line support, where the syntax for the parameter is
  `--add-lyrics=LYRICS_FILE[:DESCRIPTION[:LANG]]`.
  But to include the file's contents would need under Linux
  (I admit to not knowing the Windows syntax):

  ```
  eyeD3 --lyrics=eng:these_lyrics:"$(cat lyrics_file.txt)" some_file.mp3
  ```

Comment: Thanks, eyeD3 has more than sufficient CLI support! But what about the other half of my question: How to fetch the lyrics from LyricWiki for example?

Comment: A google search for "eyeD3 LyricWiki" found [this example](https://github.com/boyska/lyricseek/blob/master/src/lyricwiki.py) among 3,340 other results.